# FontAwesome Icons don't show up

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have this in my `<head>` code:

```
<script href="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
```

and in some of my buttons I have these:

```
<div class="scroll-up-btn">
   <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

However, they don't show up. Why? The icons should show up, I've got over 6 of them and none shows up.

Comment: Don't forget to add the necessary css files too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the `href` attribute with `src`.

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

and change `href` with `src` in your script tag

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue and I signed up on font awesome and got my own ID and replaced the numbers with my id in the link.

```
<script href="https://kit.fontawesome.com/my-id-was-here.js"></script>
```

this worked for me.
other then this a network/ internet issue can also  cause the icons to not display.